# How to get all dollar sings and the text after it in a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, marc

A marc 21 tag may content a line with several dollar signs $ like:

```
$string='10$athis is text a$bthis is text b/$cthis is text$dthis is text d';
```

I tried to match all the dollar sings and get the text after each sing, my code is:

```
preg_match_all("/\\$[a-z]{1}(.*?)/", $string, $match);
```

the output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => $a
            [1] => $b
            [2] => $c
            [3] => $d
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
        )

)
```

How can capture the text after each sing  so the output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => $a
            [1] => $b
            [2] => $c
            [3] => $d
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => this is text a
            [1] => this is text b/
            [2] => this is text c
            [3] => this is text d
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead for matching `\$` literally or end of string like

```
(\$[a-z]{1})(.*?)(?=\$|$)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lF5eF9/2)**

*PHP Code*

```
$re = "/(\\$[a-z]{1})(.*?)(?=\\$|$)/"; 
$str = "10\$athis is text a\$bthis is text b/\$cthis is text\$dthis is text d"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

**[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/ahXUK4)**

**NOTE** :- Your required result is in `Array[1]` and `Array[2]`. `Array[0]` is reserved for match found by entire regex.

Answer (score 2):

I think a simple regex is enough

```
$re = '/(\$[a-z])([^\$]*)/'; 
$str = "10\$athis is text a\$bthis is text b/\$cthis is text\$dthis is text d"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/583483)